# Serialization Error on Master Page when it's NOT in session

Tags: asp.net, serialization

Getting the following serialization error:

```
[SerializationException: Type 'ASP.master_main_master' in Assembly 'App_Web_main.master.28963a75.cit8jd_-, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.]
```

However, there's no location in the web site where the master page is added to the session.
It's also not a child object of another object that's added to the session.
How do I narrow this down?

Comment: Why are you adding a Master Page to a Session. That's not what both of them are for.

Comment: @VDWWD I'm not... that's that problem. I'm not adding the master to the session anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The problem was an object that was being saved to session had a reference to an event handler on the master page.